# ¿Como recojo valores únicos en MySQL dependiendo del año?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla donde los valores se pueden repetir en cada año (o no), necesito recoger solo las referencias del ultimo año con sus valores en el caso de que se repitan en diferentes periodos.

| Periodo | Referencia | Valor1 | Valor2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **2020** | REF1 | C1 | C2 |
| **2020** | REF2 | C2 | C3 |
| 2020 | REF3 | C0 | C3 |
| **2021** | REF1 | C11 | C22 |
| **2021** | REF2 | C22 | C33 |
| 2021 | REF4 | C0 | C3 |

Quiero conseguir este filtrado único teniendo en cuenta el año mas cercano:

| Periodo | Referencia | Valor1 | Valor2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | REF3 | C0 | C3 |
| 2021 | REF1 | C11 | C22 |
| 2021 | REF2 | C22 | C33 |
| 2021 | REF4 | C0 | C3 |

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

A continuación mi última prueba, pero se queda pensando por mas de 3 minutos y finalmente lo cancelo, necesito hacerlo en pocos segundos.

```
SELECT df.* FROM datosfase df,
(
SELECT MAX(PERIODO) AS PERIODO, REFERENCIA
FROM datosfase 
GROUP BY REFERENCIA
ORDER BY PERIODO DESC
) t1
WHERE df.PERIODO = t1.PERIODO AND df.REFERENCIA= t1.REFERENCIA
```

Comment: Pues pon también en el SELECT el valor periodo, no? Osea, la SQL está bien tal y como yo la entiendo, pero si quieres asegurarte al 100% de que el período que quieres poner, ponlo así SELECT Referencia, Valor1, Valor2, Periodo FROM ... Así, aunque te salga un dato que no quieres realmente, te puedes asegurar
Aunque quizá no es la solución que buscabas

Comment: De un periodo en especifico o de todos los periodos?

Comment: De todos. Y acabo de darme cuenta que mi consulta esta mal, ese DISTINCT no obtiene las referencias únicas porque si el valor1 o valor2 cambia ya lo toma como distinto lógicamente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Opción 1

- Creamos una consulta para obtener el `periodo` **mayor** para cada `referencia`

  ```
  SELECT
       MAX(periodo) AS periodo,
       referencia
  FROM datosfase
  GROUP BY referencia
  ```
- Si a esta consulta la movemos a una tabla derivada para hacer un `JOIN` contra todos los registros usando como filtro los valores obtenidos, vamos a obtener el resultado esperado

**Solución:**

```
SELECT A.*
FROM datosfase AS A
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            MAX(periodo) AS periodo,
            referencia
        FROM datosfase
        GROUP BY referencia
     ) AS B
     ON B.periodo = A.periodo
     AND B.referencia = A.referencia
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eCmXBLPGwsrQ5MECXFe6Mb/0)</kbd>

---

### Opción 2

- Hacemos un `LEFT JOIN` de la tabla con si misma donde la `referencia` es igual y el `periodo` es menor al unido.

  - ***Solo los registros cuyo `periodo` es el mayor NO tendrán un registro en la tabla unida (`eg: null`)***.
- Luego solo queda filtramos los registros donde la tabla unida es `NULL`

  ```
    SELECT A.*
    FROM datosfase A
        LEFT JOIN datosfase B
          ON A.referencia = B.referencia
          AND A.periodo < B.periodo
    WHERE B.periodo IS NULL;
  ```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eCmXBLPGwsrQ5MECXFe6Mb/1)</kbd>

Comment: Según el Demo parece funcionar correctamente, pero en mi tabla real (73.500 filas) va por 3 minutos ya la consulta y sigue pensando... :( No hay alguna forma más óptima?

Comment: La he cancelado a los 4 minutos. Necesito encontrar otra solución más óptima.

Comment: @AntonioRuiz con 73000 filas esto deberia terminar en segundos, aunque no tengas indices... tu problema tal vez es otro?

Comment: @Marcos me pasa lo mismo, se queda pensando con la segunda opción.

Comment: Por darte mas info, en la primera opción, la primera consulta con MAX tarda 0,078 segundos (arroja 13.000 resultados). El problema es en la segunda consulta de la primera opción donde se realiza el filtro, quizás son demasiadas comparaciones.

Comment: Ah y tengo varios índices (Primarios y Key)

Comment: @Marcos olvidalo todo, es problema de HeidiSQL o de mi red, no de la consulta:  consulta: 0,860 sec. (+ 808,031 sec. network).